# Is usage of personal pronoun I/me/etc. when writing indicative of self-centeredness?

Tags: self, writing

I have a tendency to use "I" a lot when I write.  I think I do this for one of two reasons:

1. the explanation of whatever it is that I'm writing about is easier for me to communicate if I'm explaining it in a "story" mode (for better or for worse)
2. I'm self-centered, and I think everything is about me

In my job I have to write the occasional technical paper or ask the occasional Stack Overflow question, so -- needless to say -- I often have to go back over what I wrote and edit out the "story" part of it.  Anyways, with the caveat that I've never taken a psychology course in my life, here's my question, along with a sub-question:

Is using "I" a lot when writing indicative of narcissism?  (Maybe "narcissism" isn't the best word as it's loaded -- let's say "self-centeredness.  Also, I'm not narcissistic IRL; I'd like to think I'm highly empathetic and compassionate.)

Or is using "I" a lot when writing just a tool that can be used to write more effectively?  ("PB&J: First I cut two pieces of bread, then I put peanut butter on one side...")

This idea is starting to bug the heck out of me -- I'm starting to get neurotic about it.

**Is using "I" a lot when writing good/bad/indifferent?**

Comment: You seem to be asking whether this writing style correlates with measurable psychologically relevant traits: self-centeredness and narcissisms. It seems you are primarily worried about the latter. Therefore, I suggest you focus this question about narcissism correlations, but could you please remove the personal angle (your worry), so that the question is less about you and more about objective facts. ;)

Comment: But the question IS about me!

Comment: Have a [look at the tour](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tour). Questions about one specific individual are out of scope for this site, and are usually closed. That said, it should be easy enough to abstract away so this question can stay and be considered in scope. That is, if you are interested in a more general answer. If not, a chat/forum or something similar is a better place to raise your question.

Answer (score 1):

While people with narcistic personalities (who make up less than 6% of the population - Diagnostic & Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders - 5) are self centered and may use "I statements", one's literary style of first-person prose use is not indicative of a narcistic trait or P.D., and given the salience of this literary style (used by more than 93% of the population - Reinhart's Handbook for Writers -7th ed.) this would not be considered within diagnostic criteria or be at all useful in case conceptualization. However, it may be useful to know that professionals suggest the use of first-person prose is so high across the amateur writing board because their writing is mainly introspective, or else they assert their thoughts as merely their opinions, which if anything, suggests they are reluctant to consider themselves as the sole authoritative source on the matter and leave room for others' opinion or correction.